# C# Generic Class To Write Files with Different Extensions Based on Type

Tags: c#, generics

I am serializing some classes as JSON and writing to disk in my application. I find I am doing the same thing over and over, the only difference being the file extension I may use, which is dependent on the class that was serialized. I figured I can use generics to do this but I am running into a problem with the file extension.

I have something like the following:

```
public class MyFile<T> where T: IMyAllowedDataTypes
{
  private string _path;
  public MyFile<T> CreateAndWrite(T data)
  {
       _path = Path.Combine(Cfg.BasePath,GetFileName() + GetExtension());
       File.WriteAllText(_path,JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
  }
  public T ReadMyFileContents()
  {
    return JsonConvert.Deserialize<T>(File.ReadAllText(_path));
  }
}
```

I'd like to know if there is some way to make it so I can generically call GetExtension. I already have an Interface IMyFileTypes that has GetExtension defined. I just can't figure out how to work that in. I don't want to define the extension in IMyAllowedDataTypes because I feel like the contents of a file don't really own that extension.

Comment: Inject IMyFileTypes  through constructor with your current implementation and call necessary method from injected instance.

Comment: `I don't want to define the extension in IMyAllowedDataTypes because I feel like the contents of a file don't really own that extension.`

When you save some text using a text editor, how do you decide on the file extension?

Comment: Can you show `IMyAllowedDataTypes`

Comment: How did you do it before refactoring into a generic method?